# Converting mouse (touch) position with ScreenToWorldPoint doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I googled as much as I could, but no solution.

Aim: change touch coordinates from pixels (screen left-bottom corner x0) to game coordinates in a 3D environment, although I don't need the Z position, because the camera is not moving, and I just need to track the X position and with the current state my clicks (touches) are always at positive X.

Code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
        touchPos.z = 3;
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            if (touch.position.x < 0)
                turnSpeed = 8f;
            else if (touch.position.x > 0)
                turnSpeed = -8f;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            turnSpeed = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Camera position: x: 0.027 y: 3.847 z: -2.238. I've tried setting touchPos.z = from -3 to 10., but no luck.

Comment: You should set `touch.position.z` before calling `ScreenToWorldPoint`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It says that .position is a Vector2 type and it doesnt want to register .z unfortunately.  i tried 
Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 3));
and failed. Could there be a walkaround?

Comment: I think the condition should be `if (touchPos.x < 0)`.

Comment: Great find, i thought it'd fix the problem but position X is still always positive (>0).

Comment: What is "always" mean? Have you changed the camera position, the z value, or different touch position.

Comment: No matter where i click on screen (left side, right side), script always registers input position.x >0, meaning it's still using screen coordinates instead of game coordinates i guess.

Comment: Debug.Log shows xPos: 0.027 in any unput palce. and 0.027 is coordinates of Camera's X position.

Comment: Can you edit the post to show your recent code?

Comment: Ok sir, the solution was to make two changes: 1)  if (touchPos.x < 0) instead of If (touch.position.x <0); 2) Set Z value before/when calling ScreenToWorldPoint. I went with  Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0.3f));.
Thank you very much, you were right all the way! I just needed to make those changes simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [to *shingo*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076852/converting-mousetouch-position-with-screentoworldpoint-doesnt-work#comment127365553_72076852), here's the solution:

1. Change `If (touch.position.x < 0)` to `if (touchPos.x < 0);`
2. Set the Z value before or when calling ScreenToWorldPoint. I went with:

   ```
    Vector3 touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0.3f));
   ```